# The variables for a UI library component are not found

Tags: magento2.2, uicomponent

I want to use UI library _tooltip.less component. I have a custom checkout.less file where I'm importing the component this way

`@import "source/_tooltips.less";`

However for some reason the the lessc compiler throws an error because it can't find variables. Here is the error.

> NameError: variable @color-white is undefined in
>   /Users/dmitry/Code/MyMagento/var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/frontend/MyTheme/default/en_US/css/source/lib/variables/_tooltips.less
>   on line 10, column 23:
>   @tooltip__background: @color-white;

Please advise. Thanks